# remove one object of a class from list of objects

Tags: python-3.x, list, class, listobject

I need to delete an object from the list of objects based on the condition.
In the selectDoctor method, I need to remove the object from the list in which its docid is equal to the given id and return the removed list.

```
class Doctor:
    def __init__(self, docid, docname, deptname):
        self.docid = docid
        self.docname = docname
        self.deptname = deptname

class Hospital:
        def selectDoctor(id,doclist):
        for i in range(0, len(doclist)):
            if doclist[i].docid==id: //in this condition I need to remove that object from list
                doclist.remove(i) //by removing like this it is showing error
        return doclist

for i in range(5):
    docid=int(input())
    docname=input()
    deptname=input()
    doclist.append(Doctor(docid,docname,deptname)

id=int(input())
res=Hospital.selectDoctor(id,doclist)
print(res)
```

Comment: Using list in Python, it,s easy to achieve with: doclist.pop(i)

Comment: You must not iterating list like this when deleting items. This will cause unchecked items and raise `IndexError` if any deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list in **Python3**, it,s easy to achieve this using following statements(you have at least three possibilities):

- Remove by specifying the item index

**doclist.pop(i)**

OR

- Remove by specifying the item(s) index(es) (also range of indexes also allowed e.g. **del doclist[0:2]** for removing first three items of given list) using the keyword **del**

**del doclist[i]**

- Remove by specifying the item itself

**doclist.remove(doclist[i])**

Reference: [https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=pop)

Feel free to upvote the answer after fixing your error...

Comment: The 1st method works well thank you so much.in the second one  when square bracket is used it is also working

Comment: In the second one it shows an error "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable", by changing it to doclist.remove(doclist[i]) it works.so please edit it for others –

Comment: right i edited it, my bad misstyped, thanks for remaining me about it @AlbinDavis